# Remove all elements equals to argument from vector

Tags: rust

I want to solve this leetcode task https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/fun-with-arrays/526/deleting-items-from-an-array/3247/

The main idea is to remove all elements that are equal to `val` argument

I want to use for loop in my solution but I have ownership-related error

How can I fix it?

```
Line 7, Char 17: cannot borrow `*nums` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable (solution.rs)
  |
5 |         for curr in nums.iter() {
  |                     -----------
  |                     |
  |                     immutable borrow occurs here
  |                     immutable borrow later used here
6 |             if *curr != val {
7 |                 nums[insert_idx] = *curr;
  |                 ^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
```

**My code**

```
impl Solution {
    pub fn remove_element(nums: &mut Vec<i32>, val: i32) -> i32 {
        let mut insert_idx: usize = 0;
        
        for curr in nums.iter() {
            if *curr != val {
                nums[insert_idx] = *curr;
                insert_idx += 1;
            }
        }
        return insert_idx as i32;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's straight forward, you can't have two mutable borrows in the same scope.

Comment: Iterate over `0..nums.len()` and bind `let curr = nums[idx];` — that will fix the issue